# Laravel not returning data on view->with()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having a little bit of trouble returning data on a `return view()->with();` statement.

The error I'm getting is just a blank screen with the default laravel auth navigation bar.

The MySQL table structure:

id | version | active | slug

Here is my code for you to look at.

**Function**

```
function index() {
  $changelogs = Changelogs::where('active', '1')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
  return view('changelog.index')->with('changelogs', $changelogs);
}
```

**Route (Incase you need it)**

`Route::get('/release-notes', 'Changelogs\MyController@index');`

**View**

```
@foreach($changelogs as $changelog)
<div class="row">
   div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
     div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3><a href="{{ url('/release-notes/'.$changelog->slug) }}">{{ $changelog->version }}</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        {!! $changelog->body !!}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl:dr** You need to add `->get()` to complete your [fluent query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects).

```
function index() {
  $changelogs = Changelogs::where('active', '1')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
  return view('changelog.index')->with('changelogs', $changelogs);
}
```

**bonus** all of the methods you can perform can be found in the [API docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html). One of my favourites is to echo `->toSql()` so you can sanity check the SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you dude. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

`$changelogs = Changelogs::where('active', '1')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');`

To:

`$changelogs = Changelogs::where('active', '1')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`

Hope this helps.